# How to Block Git Commits For Some Time?

Tags: git, git-branch

- I Have A Git Repository .
- In Between each Release I'm Creating One Tag For The Release.
- While Creating The Tag I Just Want To Block The Commits During That Time to My Current Working Branch.
- Any Help Would Be Appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What do you mean by "block" the commits?

Comment: block means no commites should go into my current working branch during some particular time.

Comment: If you don't want any commits to go into your branch, then don't make any commits.

Comment: Your Git repository is *yours*. It is 100% under your control. Presumably it is a clone of some other Git repository that is *not* yours. You cannot control that other Git repository (unless, of course, it's also yours, in which case you have total control). But yours is yours. You gain commits only when you make them or, using `git fetch` and related commands, ask your Git to obtain commits from other Git repositories. If you don't want that, don't *do* that.

Comment: block commites by my team

Comment: Each team-member should have his or her own repository. There is no other sensible way to work with Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> block commites by my team

That means you are not talking about your local cloned repo, but about the remote repo on the server side.
The problem is: we don't know what that server is:

- one that you do not control, like a repo hosting service (github.com, bitbucket.org, gitlab.com, ...)
- one that you are hosting on your servers (a private GitLab Community Edition instance for example)

In any case, rather than trying to block commits "for a period of time", you can protect the branch ([on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/) or [on BitBucket](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/) or [on GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/)). That works even on private instance of GitHUb, Bitbucket or GitLab.
Your collaborators would push their commits on a separate branch and make a pull request (or merge request)